# What is significant difference in GCP default service account & custom service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I have associated a custom service account to the VM, when I execute this

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

command from the VM I am getting two service accounts
`default` & `my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com/`

From Google Cloud Platform UI/web I can see only one service account associated with the VM.

The permission granted to the `my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com/` is getting reflected for the  `default` service account.
What is the significant difference between these two service accounts?
Can we associate multiple service account to the VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both entries in the metadata are the same service account.

**default** is an alias for the actual service account email address. That way you do not need to know the service account assigned to the service, which would require knowing or hardcoding the service account email address.

Comment: Thanks, John Hanley
Is there a google document for ```default is an alias for the actual service account email address``` which will help me to understand in detail?

Can we attach more than two service account to VM?

Comment: @SanvarInamdar You can only attach one service account to a VM. In your program/application you can use any number. Look at this document under **service-accounts** for aliases: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/default-metadata-values#vm_instance_metadata However, that section is not complete for what you want to know.